# Two way communication between routers within express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app that has a router for different sections of my application, each contained within individual files. At the end of each file I export the router object like so.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

//routing handlers

module.exports = router;
```

However my problem is that I am trying to implement a feature were a user is allowed to edit a post that could be displayed on the front page, therefore in order to have the most current version of the user's post I need to be able to know when the user edits the post to make the necessary changes.

I have two modules one that handles dispatching the user's posts call this module B and another that handles editing call this module A. I need to be able to have module A include handler function and an array from module B, but I also need module B to be able to be notified when to make changes to the its array that module A requires.

I have tried

```
module A

var express = require('express');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var evt = new EventEmitter();

var router = express.Router();

var modB = require('moduleB');

router.evt = evt;
module.exports = router;


Module B

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var modA = require('moduleA').evt;

modA.on('myEvent',handler);

var myArray = [....];

router.myArray = myArray;
module.exports = router;
```

This gives me an undefined for modA and throws an error. I suspect it might be the order the modules are included but anyhow I would like to obtain some feedback since I sense that this might not even be good practice.

Comment: Circular dependency issue... You might want to read https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into a common scenario for someone just starting out with express. A lot of people stick everything into routes/controllers when really the route should be very simple and just extract the data needed to figure out what the request is doing and then pass it to a service for most of the processing.

The solution is to create a Service and put the bulk of your logic and common code there, then you can wire up ModA and ModB to use the Service as needed.

EDIT with an example(not working but should give you a good starting point):

Shared Service

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var evt = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = {
  saveData: function(data) {
    // do some saving stuff then trigger the event
    evt.emit('myEvent', data);
  },
  onDataChange: function(handler) {
    evt.on('myEvent', handler);
  }
};
```

Module A

```
var service = require('SharedService.js');
// listen for events
service.onDataChange(function(e, data) {
  // do something with the data
});
```

Module B

```
var service = require('SharedService.js');
// save some data which will cause Module A's listener to fire
service.saveData(data);
```

This example above hides the implementation of EventEmitter which may or may not be desirable. Another way you could do it would be to have SharedService extend EventEmitter, then your Modules could listen/emit directly on the service.

Comment: what kind of services are your talking about? do you mind providing a link to how services are done? thanks